# Cannot go to black screen (Manual login, Ctrl+Alt+F2) and cannot stop light dm

Tags: kernel, graphics, lightdm

I have Ubuntu 12.04 installed on my Connoiseur work station with Intel Xeon processor. It has Tesla C1060 graphics card. Recently, the system encountered a kernel error and a pop up window appeared asking for the update of a particular kernel file (Sorry, I don't remember the file name). The system encountered some graphics related issues after that and it crashed. I had the system repaired and installed Ubuntu 12.04 again. Now the problem is, I am trying to install graphics card driver, in order to do that I am trying to stop 'lightdm' and the system is freezing. The manual login screen (Ctrl+Alt+F2) doesn't appear either, when I try to go to the manual login screen the system freezes. I can return to the main screen by pressing Ctrl+Alt+F7. Are these issues related? Is there a solution to this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should boot to the console.
At boot up, press shift. A grub should appear. Choose to boot with recovery mode then choose root shell.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. I followed your instructions and a grub appeared. I chose root shell but I still cannot stop the X-server. When I try to stop 'lightdm' it says,'stop: unknown instance'. I cannot install the graphics driver from the Grub also. Any help would be appreciated.